# Android: Save Notification PendingIntent to Room DB

Tags: android, push-notification, android-room

I'm setting up a portion of my app that will receive push notifications and save them into a Room database, so that they can later be displayed in a list UI. I'd like the notifications to still be tappable/actionable, so I need to save their `PendingIntent`, or some sort of Intent, but that's not something possible with Room. Is there a way I can re-create a `PendingIntent` later on? Not seeing many options available from Android's API.....if only `PendingIntent` implemented `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can re-create a PendingIntent later on?

Sure. Create it the same way that you created it in the first place (e.g., call `PendingIntent.getActivity()`.

If you did not create the `PendingIntent`, then you have no means of storing it anyway. Part of what makes a `PendingIntent` work is knowledge of what app created it. For security reasons, that means the `PendingIntent` has to actually be created by that app, not by some other app (such as yours).

Comment: I'm grabbing the `PendingIntent` directly from the `Notification` object, see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#contentIntent

Is there another way I can get all the pieces to build an `Intent` that will match the behavior of the `PendingIntent`?

Comment: @privatestaticint: No, because that `PendingIntent` was created by another app. You have no means of persisting it. You can either use it while your process is still around, or you can not use it.